# Downloaded File blurred Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a simple code which download file from url and save it to android internal data storage here is my code

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (500, 500);
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
    File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/abc.png", www.bytes);
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image> ().sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0f, 0f, texture.width,texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f),128f);
```

image downloaded successfully and shown on device perfectly

but in local storage /android /data/com.xxx.xxx/abc.png this file seems like its colors have been disturbed.

what should be the solution

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with the filtering. Check here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/602721/sprite-filtering-pointbilinear.html

Comment: @Fredrik when i share downloaded image on gmail or facebook its fine as  real but in device its colors are disturbbed
dont know its a device issue or anything else

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the correct filtering for when creating your texture2d?

Comment: If you open the image in the your app, is it blurred? Or is it blurred only when browsing trough the file explorer in the app directory?

Comment: Make sure your quality settings have "texture quality" set to "full res".

Comment: @Hristo it is fine in running App, but not in file explorer , i share it on facebook and it seems fine on wall, but in storage i don't know what is the problem with it

Comment: What is the file browser you are using?

Comment: Its huawae "cun u29" Default file browser !

Comment: Could you install [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) file browser and confirm that the quality is bad on in as well. Please use the same image as you have now.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?